# which is better add flag or set flag regard full screen and screen on

Tags: android, screen, android-activity, fullscreen

I wonder which is better in **performance** and **behavior** between the following ways in achieving:

1. Full Screen.
2. Screen On.

or both is the same

First:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

OR

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

MAYBE this is easy question but I'm still learning android development,

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: The value/type of the 2nd parameter in the 2nd option is unclear to me. But it seems wrong that the same constant could be used for both. Even tried reading the official docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags(int,%20int)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think both scenarios affect performance a lot, but in modern developing environment we prefer simplicity of coding which directly seen in

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

so definitely I vote for that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Kotlin developers

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    } else {
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
    }
```